# Parameters Constructor without IoC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, containers, inversion-of-control

I am working on project. I have a problem. I need a parameters consturctor without DI,IoC. How to make this ? Can you help me

This is my Constructer

```
 public BlogController(ILogger logger)
 {
    _logger = logger;
 }
```

I want to parameters consturctor but not use inversion of Control Container. How Can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: Research Pure DI http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/

Comment: Manually initialize all the dependencies and inject it into the dependent class